# Ask user if they want to quit OS X application

Tags: macos, swift

Similarly to apps like Microsoft Word and Garageband, I want have a dialog before my app is closed asking if the user wants to quit because there is unsaved content. With these apps, a small black dot appears in the close button on the window. Is there a way I can do this in Swift?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011179

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Objective-C it's:

```
windowShouldClose:
```

...via [NSWindowDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSWindowDelegate_Protocol)

You should be able to use this in Swift as well.

As for marking as edited, you want the `setDocumentEdited:` method.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to implement this?